# Convert Code from Unity 4 To Unity 5

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am new to installed Unity 5. where i have some problem in code.

`if (transform.parent.rigidbody)
                parentMagnitude = transform.parent.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude * 0.05f;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access `rigidbody` with your old shorthand code.

```
    Rigidbody rb = transform.parent.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if(rb != null) {
        parentMagnitude = rb.velocity.magnitude * 0.05f;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... problem has been solved